# Como inserir todos valores do array e evitar $query->execute() a cada execução do foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Como inserir todos valores do array e evitar `$query->execute()` a cada execução do foreach?

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$sql = "INSERT INTO teste(nome, email) VALUES (:nome, :email)";

try{
    $query= $conecta->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($_POST as $key => &$value) {
        $query->bindValue(':nome',$value['nome'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':email',$value['email'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
    }
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Como é PDO, é uma alternativa que pode ser válida em alguns contextos. Se for usar binds nativos, como o mysqli faz, em muitas situações é mais elegante e eficiente mandar vários "execute", que transmitem só os valores, e em tipos nativos, agilizando em muito o processo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer um unico insert é ter vários `VALUES` para gerar um sql como

```
INSERT INTO teste(nome, email) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?)
```

Seu array é multidimensional, nesse caso o primeiro passo é achata-lo criando um novo é muito **importante** que os valores esteja na ordem correta pois do contrário podem ser gravados em colunas erradas. Ainda dentro do foreach faça a concatenação da string para geral a sql no formato esperado.

Estrutura inicial do array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nome] => a
            [email] => a@a.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nome] => b
            [email] => b@b.com
        )
)
```

Estrutura convertida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => a@a.com
    [2] => b
    [3] => b@b.com
)
```

Código:

```
$itens = array(array('nome' => 'a', 'email' => 'a@a.com'),
               array('nome' => 'b', 'email' => 'b@b.com'),
               array('nome' => 'c', 'email' => 'c@c.com')                    
        );

$sql = "INSERT INTO teste(nome, email) VALUES ";

$novo = array();

foreach($itens as $item){
    $sql .= '(?,?),';
    array_push($novo, $item['nome'], $item['email']);
}

$sql = trim($sql, ',');//remova a última vírgula

$query = $conecta->prepare($sql);
if(!$query->execute($novo)){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($query->errorInfo());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer três coisas:

**1) Gerar os placeholders.**

Sabendo quantos agrupamentos de values vão ser inseridos, gerar o sql com os placeholders. Irá gerar algo como:

INSERT INTO teste(nome, email) VALUES (:nome0, :email0),(:nome1, :email1),(:nome2, :email2)

**2) Fazer os binds com os valores do array.**

**3) Executar a query fora do foreach depois de ter feito todos os binds**

No final, executa apenas uma só query com todos os insert.

```
<?php
/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';

try 
{
    $conecta = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//imaginando que se tenha uma matriz de nomes e e-mails, como é um csv
$csv_array = array(
    array(
        'nome'    =>'Teste 1',
        'email'    =>'teste1@teste.com'
    ),
    array(
        'nome'    =>'Teste 2',
        'email'    =>'teste2@teste.com'
    ),    
    array(
        'nome'    =>'Teste 3',
        'email'    =>'teste3@teste.com'
    )        
);

// gerando os placeholders e inserindo no seu sql
$qtd = count($csv_array);

$sql= 'INSERT INTO teste(nome, email) VALUES ';
$sql_fragment = '(:nome, :email),';

for($i=0; $i<$qtd; $i++)
{
    $sql_to_add = str_replace(    
                    array(':nome',':email'),    
                    array(":nome$i",":email$i"),
                    $sql_fragment 
                  );
    $sql.=$sql_to_add;
}
$sql = rtrim( $sql, ",");

//echo $sql;
//INSERT INTO teste(nome, email) VALUES (:nome0, :email0),(:nome1, :email1),(:nome2, :email2)

// fazendo os binds dos placeholders com os valores do array
try{
    $query= $conecta->prepare($sql);

    $i=0;
    foreach ($csv_array as $linha) 
    {
        $query->bindValue(":nome$i", $linha['nome'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(":email$i",$linha['email'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $i++;
    }

    $query->execute();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```