# Salvar arrays de Div clone em um Insert

Tags: php, mysql

Tenhos arrays que vem de uma div "clone" do jquery que podem ser duplicados ou até mais linhas, assim:

produto[] valor[] qtd[] total[]
produto[] valor[] qtd[] total[]

Preciso salvar esses arrays em um insert, assim:

INSERT 'tabela' (produto, valor, qtd, total) VALUES (produto[],valor[],qtd[],total[]) ;

INSERT 'tabela' (produto, valor, qtd, total) VALUES (produto[],valor[],qtd[],total[]) ;

//OBS: sei que isso nos VALUES não funciona mas é isso que preciso...

Comment: Uma ideia => [Como inserir todos valores do array e evitar $query->execute a cada execução do foreach?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174354/91)

Comment: @rray lembrando que se forem muitos registros, pode não ser muito vantajoso isso, compensando o execute repetidas vezes (desde que sejam usados BINDs nativos, o tráfego de dados é muito menor e mais rápido, pois os dados não serão enviados com separadores, e já são transmitidos como tipo nativo)

Comment: Desculpa, mas não encontrei a resposta que precisava nos links indicados e nem consegui entender o que foi explicado.. não sei se me entenderam, a div que tenho é uma clone em jquery que se duplicar os dados o insert também recebe e fica duplicado, se for 3 divs contendo as variaveis, ele recebe via post e faz o insert 3 vezes com as variaveis recebidas..