# PDO Inserir multiplas linha em um mesmo insert usando bindParam

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Possuo uma função padrão que uso para todos os meus inserts (quando possuem apenas 1 insert por vez), que seria:

```
insereRegistro($sql, $param=NULL) {
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

    //Converte os parâmetros para bindParam
    if ( isset($param) ) {
        foreach ($param as $key => $value) {
            $$key = $value;
            $query->bindParam($key, $$key);
        }
    }

    $query->execute();
    $response = $conn->lastInsertId();
}
```

Porém eu gostaria de inserir diversas linhas em uma mesma *query* `INSERT INTO table (campo, campo2) VALUES (:campo, :campo2), (:campo, :campo2)..` Mas não sei como devo proceder para que a função possa fazer esse tratamento e executar as inserções.

Não precisa ser modificado a função existente, eu posso criar uma exclusiva para esse uso, mas o problema é que não sei como devo montar a estrutura para que cara grupo de valores a ser inserido passe pelo `bindParam`.

Comment: Seria [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174354/91) ?

Comment: @rray ótimo! Estou fazendo um biblioteca de Query Builder em PHP, vou pegar essa dica.

Comment: @rray mais ou menos... Mas consegui entender a lógica e consigo resolver aqui! Vlw!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters biblioteca de body builder?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters veja se a resposta também ajuda em algo ;)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174354/como-inserir-todos-valores-do-array-e-evitar-query-execute-a-cada-execu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-d/174356#174356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base no comentário do rray, consegui elaborar uma função que me da o resultado desejado. Ao usar `bindParam` ele cria a referência com base no valor de uma variável, portanto, ao atualizar o valor da variável, o valor a ser inserido no banco de dados também será atualizado por referência (não sou entendedor de PHP mas se entendi bem, essa é a lógica).

Portanto, o que precisei fazer foi criar uma referência de variáveis no `bindParam` e posteriormente atualizar o valor da variável para cada inserção dentro de um *foreach*, ficando a função assim:

```
function insereMultiplosRegistros($sql, $param, $valor) {
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);

    foreach ($param as $key => $value) {
        $query->bindParam($key, $$value);
    }

    foreach ($valor as $row) {
        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            $$key = $value;
        }
        $query->execute();
    }

    return $conn->lastInsertId();
}
```

E para executar a função, basta passar os parâmetros como este modelo:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (campo, campo2) VALUES (:campo, :campo2)";
$param = [
    ':campo' => 'campo',
    ':campo2' => 'campo2'
];

$valor = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { //Deve ser modificado conforme a extensão da array e dos campos
    $object = (object) [
        'campo' => $key,
        'campo2' => $value
    ];
    array_push($valor, $object);
}

insereMultiplosRegistros($sql, $param, $valor);
```

Talvez isso ainda possa ser otimizado para ficar mais dinâmico e com menos código, mas foi o que consegui elaborar com meu conhecimento.